# metaclass and __prepare__ ()

Tags: python, metaclass

I am teaching myself about the `__prepare__` function. And I see this snippet at [PEP3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/#invoking-the-metaclass)

```py
# The custom dictionary
class member_table(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.member_names = []

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # if the key is not already defined, add to the
        # list of keys.
        if key not in self:
            self.member_names.append(key)

        # Call superclass
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

# The metaclass
class OrderedClass(type):

    # The prepare function
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases): # No keywords in this case
        return member_table()

    # The metaclass invocation
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        # Note that we replace the classdict with a regular
        # dict before passing it to the superclass, so that we
        # don't continue to record member names after the class
        # has been created.
        result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))
        result.member_names = classdict.member_names
        return result

class MyClass(metaclass=OrderedClass):
    # method1 goes in array element 0
    def method1(self):
        pass

    # method2 goes in array element 1
    def method2(self):
        pass
```

My question is at this line:
    `result.member_names = classdict.member_names`

How could the variable `classdict` get a attribute from the `member_table` class? I see the `__prepare__` function returns an instance of member_table, but how is the link between `member_table()` and  `classdict.member_names` generated?

Many thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is pretty straightforward, as it is exactly what prepare does.

> 3.3.3.3. Preparing the class namespace Once the appropriate metaclass has been identified, then the class namespace is prepared. If the
> metaclass has a `__prepare__` attribute, it is called as `namespace = metaclass.__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)` (where the additional
> keyword arguments, if any, come from the class definition).
>
> If the metaclass has no `__prepare__` attribute, then the class
> namespace is initialised as an empty ordered mapping.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace

Which means, the `classdict` attribute that is passed into the metaclass `__new__` and `__init__` methods is exactly the same object that is returned by `__prepare__`.

That object should be a mapping instance, that is, an object that behaves like a dict and have at least the `__setitem__` method. This `__setitem__` method is called by Python for all variables set inside the the declared class body itself.

That is, for an ordinary class, with no custom metaclass, the variables are recorded in a dictionary (an ordered dictionary, as of Python 3.6).

That happens as Python runs each statement inside the class body. This is the same object that is returned should one call `locals()` inside the class body:

```
In [21]: class M(type):
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def __prepare__(cls, *args):
    ...:         class CustomDict(dict):
    ...:             __repr__ = lambda self: "I am a custom dict: " + str(id(self))
    ...:         namespace = CustomDict()
    ...:         print("From __prepare__", namespace)
    ...:         return namespace
    ...: 
    ...:     def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
    ...:         print("From __new__:", namespace)
    ...:         return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
    ...:     
    ...:     

In [22]: class Test(metaclass=M):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         ...
    ...:     print("From class body:", locals(), locals()["__init__"])
    ...:     
    ...:     
From __prepare__ I am a custom dict: 140560887720440
From class body: I am a custom dict: 140560887720440 <function Test.__init__ at 0x7fd6e1bd7158>
From __new__: I am a custom dict: 140560887720440
```

The main use case when this feature was first designed probably was exactly the possibility of making the order of declarations inside a class body meaningful. That is, a `__prepare__` method could just return a `collections.OrderedDict`  instance, and `__new__` or `__init__` would act upon that order. As of Python 3.6, ordering of class attributes is by default - and the `__prepare__` feature remains so advanced one really has to think up of uses for it.

**update** As of Python (upcoming) 3.12, the mapping returned by `__prepare__` and passed in as the fourth argument for the metaclass `__new__` method is discarded after the metaclass `__init__` method is called. Under PEP 649, approved for Python 3.13, though, a reference to it will be kept so that the lazy annotations mechanisms can retrieve information that might exist only in it.

***Edit:*** Usually `__prepare__` is implemented as a class method as it is called before the metaclass is instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more tiny question--Can we make sure that `__prepare__` function always returns namespace that is a dict or decorated dict type (not other type)?

Comment: What do you mean by "make sure"? You should author your `__prepare__` and know what it returns. If it does not have to behave like a full mapping object - it needs only `__setitem__`, and that the code in the mclass `__init__` know how to deal with it.

Comment: I don't understand exactly the **update** part for python >= 3.12, the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace) says _"The namespace returned by __prepare__ is passed in to __new__, but when the final class object is created the namespace is copied into a new dict."_ and you wrote _"discarded after the metaclass __init__ method is called"_. Can you say smt more on this sentence?

Comment: So, up to now (from Python 3.0 (and maybe earlier) up to 3.12) the _instance_ of the mapping created by `__prepare__` has its keys and values **copied** into a new dict, (accessible via proxy) as the new class `__dict__`. From Python 3.13 on, due to annotation machinery, a reference to that object itself might be kept around in order for lazy evaluation of annotations to be possible, as for PEP 649

Answer (score 1):

The comment in your `__new__` is confusing things about the role of the object returned by `__prepare__` and the accepted answer does not clear it up.

**The namespace returned by `__prepare__` is just a temporary object during class creation that will be passed to `__new__`, it is not the namespace that your class will use at runtime after creation.**
(classes have an optimized namespace-object called mappingproxy which enforces keys being strings)

You can see the effect in this script:

```
class CustomDict(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f"setting {key} to {value}")
        super().__setitem__(key, value)


class PrintAssignmentMeta(type):

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcs, name, bases):
        return CustomDict()
    
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace):
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)


class PrintAssignmentClass(metaclass=PrintAssignmentMeta):
    # these print
    a = 3
    b = 4

# this does not print because the class-namespace no longer involves your custom setitem
PrintAssignmentClass.c = 5

# but all three are in the namespace of the class
print(PrintAssignmentClass.a, PrintAssignmentClass.b, PrintAssignmentClass.c)
print(PrintAssignmentClass.__dict__)
```