# Why str() and type() returns different type names for db.Column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning the Flask SQLAlchemy.

I initialize the SQLAlchemy normally:

```
db= SQLAlchemy(app = app)
```

And define tables with class like this:

```
class Table1(db.Model):
    col1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I checked the type of `db.Column` as below.

```
str(db.Column)
"<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column'>"
type(db.Column)
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.visitors.TraversibleType'>
```

Why the types are different?

### ADD 1 - 12:17 PM 6/21/2022

Suppose we have:

```
class C:
   pass
```

I think below 2 pieces of code [are equivalent, just different syntax](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/#example-2):

```
class X(C):
   pass
```

And:

```
X = type('X', (C,), {})
```

But when it comes to the `Enum` like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72682119/why-typeenumtype-return-enummeta-in-python/), some error happens:

```
from enum import Enum

class X1(Enum):  # <========= this is OK.
   pass

X2 = type('X2', (Enum,), {}) # <========= This is error
```

And the error is:

```
...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 175, in __new__
    enum_members = {k: classdict[k] for k in classdict._member_names}
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_member_names'
```

Not sure why.

Comment: Comparing the difference between the output of `str(object)` and `type(object)`, the answer should become obvious.  Though ShadowRanger already gave a full explanation already so best to read that.

Comment: For those that care about what is under the hood, [this thread, and the answer that I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72682119/why-typeenumtype-return-enummeta-in-python/) covers the relationship of classes to the `type` "function".

Comment: @metatoaster Thanks for the info. I found some weird thing based on the thread you mentioned. Could you take a look at my ADD 1? Thanks.

Comment: @metatoaster just correct a typo in ADD 1. Mistyped `Enum` to `object`.

Comment: That's because `Enum` uses the [`__prepare__` classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827708/), where [it provides a custom `classdict` argument as a `_EnumDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.13/Lib/enum.py#L143-L155). While `X2 = type('X2', (Enum,), _EnumDict())` may work in 3.8, it still bypassed the `__prepare__`, and won't work [after this change in 3.9.2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Lib/enum.py#L170), thus the full equivalent is `type('X2', (Enum,), EnumMeta.__prepare__('X2', (Enum,),))`. Note this one-liner cannot add attributes.

Comment: However, splitting out the `EnumDict` construction by taking the return value of `__prepare__` and then populate it with the desired attributes, e.g.  `clsdict = EnumMeta.__prepare__('Color', (Enum,),)`, and then `clsdict['RED'] = 1`, finally `Color = EnumMeta('Color', (Enum,), clsdict)`, now you can `Color(1)` which will produce an instance `<Color.RED: 1>`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `db.Column` is a class, which has a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python/6581949#6581949) of `TraversibleType`. Even classes are instances of other classes (most are instances of `type` itself), but in this case it's using a custom metaclass.

`str` reports the class itself (`Column`), `type` reports the metaclass (which is then stringified automatically by the REPL).