# why type(enumType) return EnumMeta in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
   RED=1;

>>>type(Color);
<class 'enum.EnumMeta'>
```

I thought the type of Color should be "class Enum", but why it returns "enum.EnumMeta"?

this behavior is different from common case, What is under the hood?

Comment: where are the 'EnumMeta' class from?

Comment: `Enum` is the *superclass* of `Color`, not the type of `Color`.

Comment: That's the metaclass for the type `Enum`.  `type(cls)` gets the [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41338238) for the `cls`, e.g. `type(object)` => `type`

Comment: @metatoaster  e.g. `class Foo(object): __metaclass__=enum.EnumMeta;
>> type(Foo)`     but it returns <class 'type'> but not the specified metaclass.

Comment: Try instead `class Foo(metaclass=enum.EnumMeta): pass`.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the class `Color` you have created is a direct subclass of the type `Enum` (from the module `enum`), and so `Enum`'s relationship to `Color` is in fact the parent class (a.k.a. super class) of `Color`, or that `Color` is the subclass of `Enum`:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> 
>>> class Color(Enum):
...     RED = 1
... 
>>> issubclass(Color, Enum)
True
```

Now, `type()` is not simply but a function, though at first it may seem like one, as passing a single argument to it reveals the type of the argument passed.  Generally, it may determine the underlying class that underpin some object instance, e.g.:

```
>>> obj = object()
>>> type(obj)
<class 'object'>
```

Likewise, if you instantiate an instance of `Color` like so, and try to find the resulting type:

```
>>> c = Color(1)
>>> type(c)
<enum 'Color'>
```

So far so good, but what is the type of the class definition itself, such as `object`?

```
>>> type(object)
<class 'type'>
>>> class Demo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> print(Demo)  # effectively calls `str(Demo)` before printing
<class '__main__.Demo'>
>>> type(Demo)
<class 'type'>
```

Both of these is getting closer to what you have done with `type(Color)` - what you did was effectively finding the underlying foundation that created the class.  In both the case of `object` and its subclass `Demo`, that foundation is `type`.  This reveals something - that `type` is not simply a function, but is actually a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python/6581949#6581949) (scroll to "What are metaclasses (finally)" section where it goes in depth about what `type` actually is).  But in brief, we can create a metaclass by subclassing directly from `type` instead of `object`:

```
>>> class SubType(type):
...     pass
```

Now we have a subclass of `type`, that may be used as a `metaclass`.  Now, create a new class and specify its `metaclass` to be `SubType` by doing the following.

```
>>> class Demo2(metaclass=SubType):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Demo3(Demo2):
...     pass
... 
>>> print(Demo2)  # effectively calls `str(Demo2)` before printing
<class '__main__.Demo2'>
>>> type(Demo2)
<class '__main__.SubType'>
>>> type(Demo3)
<class '__main__.SubType'>
```

Armed with the knowledge gained from the above example, specifically how the situation similar to the question might be created, this revealed that `Enum` and its subclasses have `EnumMeta` as the underlying metaclass, and `type(Enum)` and `type(Color)` simply revealed this fact.  You can in fact also create a new class with `EnumMeta` as the metaclass like so:

```
>>> from enum import EnumMeta
>>> 
>>> class BrokenEnum(metaclass=EnumMeta):
...     pass
... 
>>> print(BrokenEnum)  # effective calls `str(BrokenEnum)` before printing
<enum 'BrokenEnum'>
>>> type(BrokenEnum)
<class 'enum.EnumMeta'>
```

Thus this is what was seen in the question.  Though this is a broken enum class simply because it doesn't have the full mechanism that the `EnumMeta` expects for this type of class to function correctly, for that the reference implementation `Enum` should be consulted to ensure that the resulting class can work like the `Enum` class.

---

So some may have wondered how does the three argument invocation of `type` fit into here?  Since the simple one-liner that can dynamically produce a class (i.e. `type('Cls', (object,), {})` is effectively `class Cls(object): pass`), this could be easily done for `Enum`?  Actually no, because of the [`__prepare__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827708/metaclass-and-prepare) classmethod for metaclasses can potentially be used to provide a custom mapping, including subclasses of any mapping table, so it must first be used to invoked to produce one (as invoking `type` as done earlier will not call this `__prepare__` class method - `Enum` has [this `__prepare__` classmethod](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.12/Lib/enum.py#L164-L177) to produce a `enum_EnumDict` instance).  So, to replicate the first definition using `type`, something like the following may be done:

```
>>> clsdict = EnumMeta.__prepare__('Color2', (Enum,),)
>>> clsdict['RED'] = 1
>>> Color2 = EnumMeta('Color2', (Enum,), clsdict)  # `type` may be used instead of `EnumMeta`, but this is to be consistent
>>> Color2(1)
<Color2.RED: 1>
```

Though upon further experimentation, a one-liner can still be done, but be warned, this is grotesque and may randomly stop working due to 1) `_EnumDict` is not considered a public interfaces for it is prefixed with `_`; 2) this depend on a dunder operator that may be overridden in the future - see how [in a prior minor version `3.9.1`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Lib/enum.py#L129-L134) did not have [this new change](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Lib/enum.py#L170) introduced in `3.9.2` as an example how the simple one-liner can break in subsequent version.  Now if you are ready, strap in, because this abuses the `:=` operator, `any`, `map`, `zip`, along with operator chaining in a mess that no one should ever, ever write.

```
>>> Color3 = EnumMeta('Color3', (Enum,), (_ := EnumMeta.__prepare__(
...     'Color3', (Enum,),)) and any(map(_.__setitem__, *(zip(*{
...         'RED': 1,
...         'GREEN': 2,
...         'BLUE': 3,
...     }.items())))) or _
... )
>>> Color3(1)
<Color3.RED: 1>
>>> Color(2)
<Color.GREEN: 2>
>>> Color(3)
<Color.BLUE: 3>
```

I did break that one long line up for readability, and made it possible to pass in a standard looking `dict` nested within for class attributes to be created with the resulting class for "ease of use" (yes the keys and values may be passed as separate list, but I'd argue that's less friendly to edit afterwards).  Explanation on how this was put together will be left as a reader's exercise.